# Why couldn't Python use the `as` keyword to do assignment expressions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8, python-assignment-expression

Python 3.8 introduced the "walrus operator" `:=` to do [assignment expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html).  I assume they considered using the keyword `as` but rejected it.  Are there existing syntactic cases for `as` that precluded using it for assignment expressions?

To use an example from the Python docs:

```
# Actual Python 3.8 syntax
if (n := len(a)) > 10:
    print(f"List is too long ({n} elements, expected <= 10)")

# Why not this?
if (len(a) an n) > 10:
    print(f"List is too long ({n} elements, expected <= 10)")
```

Here's another example:

```
# Actual Python 3.8 syntax
while (block := f.read(256)) != '':
    process(block)

# Why not this?
while f.read(256) as block:
    process(block)
```

Comment: Note to Mods: not sure why this is opinion based.  I was asking about existing syntactic uses of `as` that were incompatible.  The accepted answer provides these.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Insight into questions like these ("why did they do X instead of Y") can usually be gained by reading the relevant PEP, which often has a section on "things we considered but rejected".

https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/#alternative-spellings

> EXPR as NAME:
> stuff = [[f(x) as y, x/y] for x in range(5)]
> Since EXPR as NAME already has meaning in import, except and with statements (with different semantics), this would create unnecessary confusion or require special-casing (e.g. to forbid assignment within the headers of these statements).

The page goes on to list other reasons that using `as` in this way was considered to be potentially confusing.

Comment: Note: I didn't just know the PEP number off the top of my head, nor would I expect anyone else to; I googled "walrus operator PEP" and it was the first hit.  :)  Every change made to the Python spec has a corresponding PEP with a very lengthy discussion behind it.

Answer (score 1):

In python the `as` keyword is already heavily used for other functionalities, such as aliasing in `import` statements, exception handling, and with context managers. Overloading the `as` keyword to also handle assignment expressions would introduce ambiguity and complexity in parsing Python code.

A. Alias in imports: `import numpy as np`

B. Exception handling: `except Exception as e`

C. Context managers: `with open("file.txt") as f`

Using `as` for assignment expressions could create confusion when reading the code. It would be challenging to quickly distinguish whether `as` is being used for aliasing, exception handling, with a context manager, or for assignment expressions.

The walrus operator `:=` was introduced to clearly demarcate assignment expressions, making it easier to understand the intent of the code.
It allows for concise and unambiguous code, which aligns with Python's philosophy of readability and simplicity.